# Infer type of object of classes

Tags: javascript, typescript

Building a form config builder, want to infer types dynamically, here's the minimal reproduction code

```
interface Meta {
    optional: boolean
}

class Base<Type = any> {
    readonly _type!: Type
    baseMeta: Meta

    constructor() {
        this.baseMeta = {
            optional: false,
        }
    }

    optional() {
        this.baseMeta.optional = true
        return this;
    }
}

class FieldText extends Base<string> {

}

class FieldNumber extends Base<number> {

}


class Field {
    static text() {
        return new FieldText();
    }

    static number() {
        return new FieldNumber();
    }
}

const fields = {
    fieldText: Field.text(),
    fieldNumber: Field.number(),
    fieldTextOptional: Field.text().optional(),
    fieldNumberOptional: Field.number().optional(),
}
```

Given code above I want to achieve one of the following types, doesn't matter which one

```
type ExpectedType = {
    fieldText: string;
    fieldNumber: number;
    fieldTextOptional: number | undefined;
    fieldNumberOptional: number | undefined;
}
```

Also fine

```
type ExpectedTypeWithOptionalKeys = {
    fieldText: string;
    fieldNumber: number;
    fieldTextOptional?: number;
    fieldNumberOptional?: number;
}
```

I've gotten to infering types, but can't figure out why the optional property is not taken in consideration

```
type ExtractFieldType<O, T> = O extends true ? T | undefined : T;

type SchemaType<T extends Record<string, Base>> = {
    [Property in keyof T]: ExtractFieldType<T[Property]['baseMeta']['optional'], T[Property]['_type']>;
};

type Schema = SchemaType<typeof fields>;
```

`type Schema` results in:

```
type Schema = {
    fieldText: string;
    fieldNumber: number;
    fieldTextOptional: string;
    fieldNumberOptional: number;
}
```

this `O extends true ? T | undefined : T` always returns T, doesn't take actual value of optional into consideration

### EDIT:

after a bit of fumbling around with [@kelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18244921/kelly)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73626879/infer-type-of-object-of-classes/73626958#73626958) for providing a value to the optional function here's the end result:

```
    optional<T extends boolean>(value?: T): Base<Type, T> {
        const optional = typeof value === 'boolean' ? value : true;
        this.baseMeta.optional = optional as Optional;
        return this as unknown as Base<Type, T>;
    }
```

first you can't have a default value as then Typescript get's angry with:

```
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'boolean' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'boolean'.(2322)
```

So we simply make value `optional` and then the rest works pretty much as Kelly explained

except for `return this as unknown as Base<Type, T>;`

if you remove the `as unknown` part you get the following error:

```
Conversion of type 'this' to type 'Base<Type, T>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'Base<Type, Optional>' is not comparable to type 'Base<Type, T>'.
    Type 'Optional' is not comparable to type 'T'.
      'Optional' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'boolean'.(2352)
```

Here's the final working in [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-DjQJ43I88WS4n0FX5Cn5pnboL29Jkn3qz+KAAolRzDUIMr4kN202W92ZNq9XTQ9LygGRZ2gIDfxXXdpFzEDkAAHzZegIGbOM6EgysQJPWDwKgRDkLoVDQHfZRVgAenI6w-CIawECQAg4GYDh1AfZBn1fSAP3MAB1YBOhwgBpCATCYNsDygmh-wqQCJKw6swJAzDk2gylrjg6tlMtbCYPUvCyNYz9nwqRAwD7YVcFFIYcAdPZMSqFAESMAj2SItD32QZJlAENiAGUEA6CBrTgCznJcR0mAAJQgUooDoLUZJAXV7GdGx7GhI5uCyr9FgAbQABSgMRoDiZBQGQDkRIBZAjAAXRkYyoFM8z4mMAqivMKA4lq3KoVxTAIR6iEb3IQbnna4qupMIbYniQaxVUby-ICoK4CGfzAuCiyH2qpcGAW9QgA)

Comment: Are you sure about the last one? It always returns `T | undefined` for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `optional` in `Meta` is *always* `boolean`. You need to store the value in a generic to use later:

```
interface Meta<Optional extends boolean> {
    optional: Optional;
}

class Base<Type = any, Optional extends boolean = false> {
    readonly _type!: Type
    baseMeta: Meta<Optional>

    constructor() {
        this.baseMeta = {
            optional: false as Optional,
        }
    }

    optional(): Base<Type, true> {
        this.baseMeta.optional = true as Optional; // needs unsafe assert, or alternatively //@ts-ignore
        return this as Base<Type, true>;
    }
}
```

Then when you change it with `optional`, trick TypeScript into believing you are returning `Base<Type, true>` instead.

You only need to change this. Your original solution now works.

---

Addressing the followup in the comments:

```
optional<T extends boolean = true>(value: T = true): Base<Type, T> {
    this.baseMeta.optional = value as Optional;
    return this as Base<Type, T>;
}
```

Comment: Amazing, what about if i wanted to provide a variable into the optional function?

Comment: @Mykolas What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: let's say i want to dynamically make it optional based on an argument?
optional<T extends boolean>(value: T = true): Base<Type, T> {
    this.baseMeta.optional = value as Optional;
    return this as Base<Type, typeof value>;
}
Just a question if this is possible or not? What you provided answers the question asked fully

Comment: Added an edit to show the optional function with a param, Thank you @kelly you've been amazing help